# access iframe elements

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button

I have an iframe

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" frameborder="0" src="datalist.aspx">
```

In my datalist.aspx I have a radio button with id "rdb". Is it possible to access the id of radio button through iframe in my page where iframe is defined. I really want to identify if the radio button has been clicked or not in javascript code. If I can get its id then work will be easier.

Comment: The most important infomation that you must give first before asks this question is the page inside iframe is in the same domain of parent page.

Comment: what do u mean by that "same domain of parent page"

Comment: Sorry for jumping in and answering Soul_Master's question, but a domain name is the first part of the url, for example someaddr.com or someaddr.co.uk. If the iframe does not share the same domain as the parent it is not possible to communicate between them as the browser will prevent it for security reasons.

Comment: Soul_Master is asking if the page in the iFrame is a part of the same website and hosted with the same domain name (yourdomain.com) as the parent page. If it isn't, you're trying to do something that browsers will disallow for security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, in the html of parent:

```
<html>
  <script>
    function check_radio() {
      alert(window.frames["inner_frame"].document.getElementById("rdb").checked)
    }
  </script>
  <iframe name="inner_frame" src="iframe_inner.html"></iframe>
  <a href="javascript:check_radio()">Check Radio Button 1</a>
</html>
```

Where the html of the inner frame (iframe_inner.html) is:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="rdb"     value="1"> Radio Button 1
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="another" value="1"> Radio Button 2
```

Comment: my frame id is frame1,so when i try to access it using
if(window.frames["frame1"].document.getElementById("rdb").checked))
alert("you have checked");
then it says object required

Comment: What browser are you using? It might be differ from Firefox to IE